# SQL: Sum the Product of 2 Columns and Display on each Corresponding Record

Tags: sql

Having trouble getting the SQL just right to do the following. I have a table that contains:

```
ID |Serial# |Part #|Cost|Qty|
1  |ABC     |1     |100 | 1 |
2  |ABC     |2     |100 | 2 |
3  |ABC     |3     |100 | 1 |
4  |DEF     |1     |100 | 1 |
5  |DEF     |2     |100 | 1 |
```

I'd like to add a 6th column "Total Cost" that Multiplies "Cost" by "Qty" and Sums it, grouped by Serial #, then adds that value to each record. Meaning, the "Total Cost" for ID 1,2,3 would be 400, and for ID 4,5 it would be 200.

I think I need to do a sub-query to do the sum, then join with the outer query that displays the "Cost" and "Qty" but I keep getting errors because I can't include "Part #" in the sub query.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? + add your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method which should work on just about any database:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.total_cost
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Serial, SUM(Cost*Qty) AS total_cost
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Serial
) t2
    ON t1.Serial = t2.Serial;
```

If your database has analytic functions, then we can avoid the subquery:

```
SELECT t.*,
    SUM(Cost*Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY Serial) total_cost
FROM yourTable t;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was over complicating it.